# html parsing - replacing newline character

Tags: parsing, html-parsing

I have created a simple html parsing code which gets text content from a given Xpath.

My code:

```
XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
CleanerProperties props  = new CleanerProperties();
props.setNamespacesAware(false);    
XPath xpathi = xFactory.newXPath();
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner(props);
TagNode node = cleaner.clean(rawContent);
org.w3c.dom.Document doc = new DomSerializer(props).createDOM(node);
Object[] obj = xpathi.compile("//div[@class='answer']").evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

In this I am getting the obj populated with expected answers. But the \n character in answers are replaced with empty string.
eg) If the answer is like,
one
two
three

I am getting onetwothree
I want to get one two three

For this do I need to set any property in the CleanerProperties?

Any suggestions plz..

Comment: I want to preserve the line breaks..

Comment: Narrowed down the issue. The source html is like one <br> two <br> three. Since the line breaks doesn't have proper close tags, they seem to be removed by the html cleaner. So I am getting the text concatenated without space. Any ideas to resolve this?